# Android conditional remove fragment from back-stack using Navigation Components

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, navgraph

In an Android APP I have the following navigation using Navigation Components and Nav Graph:

*Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C -> Fragment D -> Fragment E*

Anyway the back navigation must be customized:

*Fragment A <- Fragment B <- Fragment C <- Fragment D*

*Fragment A <- Fragment E*

I can set *app:popUpTo* and *app:popUpToInclusive* directly in xml Nav Graph only for *actionDtoE*, becouse the "removing" from back-stack of Fragment B and Fragment C must be conditional, only if I reach Fragment E.

How can I do this conditional remove of fragment from back-stack using Navigation Components?

Answer (score 0):

You can override FragmentD back action using `onBackPressed` in activiy or using callbacks in fragment. In my case I used activity.

Fragment A <- Fragment E

```
   override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.EFragment && condition) {
            navController.popBackStack(R.id.aFragment, false)
            return
        }
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
```

Other variations:

Fragment A <- Fragment E => `navController.popBackStack(R.id.aFragment, true)`

Fragment B <- Fragment E => `navController.popBackStack(R.id.bFragment, false)`